# Parse specific, how to save query results on an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks, parse-platform

Im very new to iOS and `PFQuery` and I need your help please

IM trying to store the array of objects obtained form `PFQuery` into a local `NSArray`, Im trying to do it inside `if (!error)` but it does not leave the block, once the block terminates so does the values for it on my array.

```
 //InstallersDirectory.m

 @interface InstallersDirectoryTVC ()

 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *supervisors;


 @end

 //more code goes here
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];


  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"InstallersInfo"];
  [query whereKey:@"supervisor" equalTo:@"yes"];
  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

      if (!error) {
          for (PFObject *object in objects) {
              self.supervisors = [objects valueForKey:@"supervisor"];
          }


  }else {
      NSLog(@"Error, %@ %@",error,[error userInfo]);
  }
}];
```

Everything works inside the block, like self.supervisors.count or `NSLog`, but it doesn't leave the block at all. Could you please tell me how I can get those values store definitely to self.supervisors?

Thanks !!

edit | comment

Comment: You're querying for InstallersInfo objects that have the string "yes" in the "supervisor" key, yet in the completion block you're setting an NSArray to be equal to the contents of the "supervisor" key. Both statements do not make a lot of sense together. What type of data is stored in "supervisor"? Is it a string, or an array?

Answer (score 0):

If you still need help on this issue, here is a suggestion or two:

first, self.supervisors is a NSArray.  As a NSArray it has to be fully initialized and populated at creation time.  So, even though you are iterating through your results, you are creating a new array each time which means only the last iteration would likely be stored in self.supervisors.

try this instead,

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *supervisors;

in your block:

```
[self.supervisors addObject:object];
//note: this will put the entire returned object in your mutable array
```

then later outside your block:
to list all the supervisors:

```
 for (PFObject *supervisor in self.supervisors) {
        NSLog(@"supervisor info:%@",supervisor);
 }
```

To get the 4th supervisor in the list:

```
PFObject *superVisorNumber4 = [self.supervisors objectAtIndex:4];
```

To get the phone number from that supervisor (making this up :)

```
NSString *phone = [superVisorNumber4 objectForKey:@"phone"];
```

hope that helps